# Why this stochastic integral is not necessarily a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

I am studying Stochastic Integral theory. My professor said that given $M_t$ a continuous martingale and $p\in (1,\infty)$ the stochastic integral
$$\int_0^t M_s^{2p-1} \mathrm{sgn}(M_s) \mathrm{d}M_s, \quad \quad \quad (*)$$
is always a local martingale but not necessarily a martingale.

I cannot understand why $(*)$ is not a martingale. Since $M_s^{2p-1} \mathrm{sgn}(M_s)$ is continuous, then $M_s^{2p-1} \mathrm{sgn}(M_s)$ is predicatable, and therefore $(*)$ should be a martingale. What am I confusing?

Moreover, why is $(*)$ a local martingale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a progressively measurable $(H_s)_{s\in[0,t]}$ satisfies $\int_0^t\vert H_s\vert^2\,d\langle M\rangle_s<+\infty$ almost surely, then the stochastic integral is a local martingale. If moreover $\mathbb E\left[\int_0^tH_s^2\,d\langle M\rangle_s\right]<+\infty$, then it is a martingale.

Here you would need that $\mathbb E\left[\int_0^tM_s^{4p-2}\,d\langle M\rangle_s\right]$ to conclude that it is a martingale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have a reference that I can check why $\int_0^t |H_s|d\langle M\rangle_s <\infty$ a.s. implies that the stochastic integral is a martingale?

Comment: It would imply that the stochastic integral is a local martingale, not necessarily a martingale. Note that this condition is satisfied when $H$ has continuous trajectories, which is the case of your process. If you want a reference about these kind of things, I can suggest for example Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus, written by Jean-François Le Gall.